# passing authentication parameters to xsjs

Tags: javascript, hana, hana-xs

We have SAP HANA 1.0 SPS12. We are using xsjs for sending email alerts.
We have below URL of same -

```
https://localhost:4300/ALERTS/TEST.xsjs?id=1&name=abc
```

id and name are parameters which will be consumed in xsjs. I need to consume URL of xsjs through Informatica. We need to send authentication details viz. Username and password through URL.

As this xsjs have form based and basic authentication, how do we consume it through Informatica?

How do we send authentication parameter as a part of URL as we have to consume this service through Informatica?

Please find below `.xsaccess` file for same -

```
{
     "exposed" : true,  
                 
     "authentication" :                                            
            {
               "method": "Form"   
            },
  
     "cache_control" : "must-revalidate", 

     "cors" :                      
            {
             "enabled" : false
            }, 
                     
     "enable_etags" : false,

     "force_ssl" : false,
     
     "prevent_xsrf" : true
}
```

Comment: What is the question here? Please see [ask] for guidelines on how to ask questions.

Comment: Question is how do we send authentication parameter as a part of URL as we have to consume this service through Informatica

Comment: @AnirudhD did you get any clue on how to do this?